# We would like to switch from Checkboxlist to regular checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Initially, we have a checkboxlist control on the markup page with ID="recs"

On that markup, we have check all / uncheck all checkboxes. This way, users can check one checkbox or several checkboxes.

We were able get the value(s) of checked boxes with the following code:

```
Protected Sub btnGetCheck_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    Thread.Sleep(9000)

    Dim uItems As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To recs.Items.Count - 1
        If recs.Items(i).Selected Then
            If uItems <> "" Then uItems = uItems & ","
            uItems = uItems & _
                "You checked" & recs.Items(i).Text & "from the db"

        End If
    Next
    Response.Redirect("sendto.aspx?p=" & Server.UrlEncode(uItems))
End Sub
```

This worked real well for us.

However, this morning, we were asked to add more columns to the markup. It turns out that this was not possible.

We decided to switch from checkboxlist to checkboxs using gridview.

I would appreciate asssistance with rewriting the above code to get checked items from the checkboxes in gridview.

Gridview code snip is below.

```asp
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  HeaderStyle-CssClass = "header"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Arial"  OnRowDataBound = "RowDataBound"
    Font-Size = "11pt" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor = "#C2D69B" >
   <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="checkAll" runat="server" onclick = "checkAll(this);" />
        </HeaderTemplate> 
       <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox ID="recs" runat="server" onclick = "Check_Click(this)" />
       </ItemTemplate> 
    </asp:TemplateField> 
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "custid" HeaderText = "Customer ID" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "firstname" HeaderText = "First Name" />
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "lastname" HeaderText = "Last Name"/>
    <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width = "150px" DataField = "os"  HeaderText = "OS"/>
   </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
       <asp:Button ID="btnGetCheck" runat="server" Text="Get Checked Items" onclick="btnGetCheck_Click" /><br />


Dim uItems As String = String.Empty

        For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

            If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Checked Then

                If uItems <> String.Empty Then

                    uItems += ","

                End If

                uItems += "You checked " & CType(r.Cells(1).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Text & " from the db."
                Response.Write(uItems)
                Response.End()

            End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the rows of the GridView and grab a reference to the checkboxes using the FindControl method.

```
Dim uItems As String = String.Empty

For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

    If CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Checked Then

        If uItems <> String.Empty Then

            uItems += ","

        End If

        uItems += "You checked " & CType(r.Cells(0).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Text & " from the db."

    End If

Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much @NoAlias for your prompt response.

I am getting the following error:

Error 1 Expression is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView', which is not a collection type. which is on this line:

For Each r As GridViewRow In GridView1 highlighting GridView1

Any ideas what the error is?

Comment: thank you very, very much The error is gone but I am not getting any values. It is entirely my fault for not explaining it well.

Looking at the markup I posted, if a checkbox for a row is checked, we would like to get the custid of that row. If say for instance, 3 checkboxes are checked, get the 3 custIds associated with it.

Is it doable?

Lots of thanks.

Comment: r.Cells(1).Text would be the custID.

Comment: I am very sorry @NoAlias. Please forgive me for my slowness.

I have updated the code above. Can you please see what I am doing wrong? I still can't get the value of custid when I check a box next to it. I keep getting blank screen.

Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Well, @NoAlias, all the watch window is showing me is: uItemss "You checked from the db." String As you can see, it isn't getting the custID value.

Comment: "You checked " & CType(r.Cells(1).FindControl("recs"), CheckBox).Text should be "You checked " & r.Cells(1).Text

Comment: Many thanks for all your help.

It is much appreciated.

I tried that before but the screen was blank. It turns out that I need to use If Not IsPostback on pageLoad event. It is working now.

Thanks alot for your patience.